# How to show user first name + last name in top bar in sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

In sharepoint in topest bar shown the active directory user name. I want to show user first name + last name instead of it.

How I can do that?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found some information on: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/f40c2e71-b0eb-4d4e-8afc-093024001502/display-names-show-as-domainusername-instead-of-first-last?forum=sharepointadminprevious

1. go to application management-manage service > user profile service > manage user profiles > make sure the preferred name looks like First name Last name.
2. open ADUC on your DC, find the user and check whether the display name is First name Last name.
3. try to create a new user profile service application, then start profile synchronization, then select start full